# Access denied for user in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, access-denied

I have followed all necessary steps while connecting my JAVA program to my database on mysql.
my code snippet is as follows:

```
 final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/electionDatabase/";
 final String User ="electionUser";
 final String Password="election";
 Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"electionUser", Password);

 String sql = "select stateId from stateWiseSeats";
```

But still I am getting an error saying:

```
 Access denied for user 'electionUser'@'localhost' to database 'electionDatabase/'
```

i have rechecked my username and password on mysql commandline and also I granted added all the privileges to the user for the specified database. Still I am getting the error. Why?

Comment: Try it again after removing last forward slash form DB_URL.

Comment: when i remove slash i get null pointer exception

Comment: what is Exception saying? You are now moving in the right direction of solving this issue.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at electionClass.main(electionClass.java:27)

Comment: Look at the Line no 27. What is there?

Comment: String sql = "SELECT stateId from stateWiseSeats"; //line25
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  //line 26

Comment: `stmt` is null. Have you initialized the `stmt` anywhere in code. Look at this [sample code](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

Comment: yes , stmt = conn.createStatement();

Comment: If the problem is still there then please share your complete code for quicker solution.

Comment: ok , I will check the code over again and then get back to you if its not working.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the error message:

```
'electionDatabase/'
```

is considered as the database name as per the URL provided and hence it is trying to access a non-existent database and throws this error.

Try removing the slash at the end of the URL and execute.

Comment: I tried everything , with slash removed it gives null

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  // setup the connection with the DB.
  connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/electionDatabase?"
          + "user=electionUser&password=election");
```

This should solve your problem. Probably the trailing forward slash at the end of DB_URL is causing the issue.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
       ON my_database.* 
       TO 'my_user'@'localhost'
       IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password' 
       WITH GRANT OPTION;